# what does it mean "transaction log data replay into database" for MS Exchange server

Tags: database, high-availability, microsoft-exchange

I am new to MS Exchange DAG. what does it mean "transaction log data replay into database" for MS Exchange server?

Answer (score 0):

All transaction happening on MS Exchange are recorded in transaction log and then applied to database (where all mailboxes are eventually stored). This means that if you have the transaction log (by means of proper backup), one can replay log file to reconstruct the entire Mailbox database from the transaction logs.This is helpful in recovery especially in case of events like corrupted storage, database or a sudden power loss on the server. By the way this strategy of applying all changes to first a log file and then to the eventual storage is something which is widely done by almost all persistent datastores.